# Azure service bus subscription enable auto delete bicep

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am reading this doco https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.servicebus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions?pivots=deployment-language-bicep and below is the list of editable specs of service bus  subscription using bicep

```
resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions@2022-10-01-preview' = {
  name: 'string'
  parent: resourceSymbolicName
  properties: {
    autoDeleteOnIdle: 'string'
    clientAffineProperties: {
      clientId: 'string'
      isDurable: bool
      isShared: bool
    }
    deadLetteringOnFilterEvaluationExceptions: bool
    deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration: bool
    defaultMessageTimeToLive: 'string'
    duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow: 'string'
    enableBatchedOperations: bool
    forwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo: 'string'
    forwardTo: 'string'
    isClientAffine: bool
    lockDuration: 'string'
    maxDeliveryCount: int
    requiresSession: bool
    status: 'string'
  }
}
```

I am unable to find "Never auto delete" on the bicep specs above. The closest thing to it is "autoDeleteOnIdle" which is a that we pass in bicep to let azure know how long before deleeting the message. But it seems "never auto delete" does not appear at the config above. Any ideas how to set "never auto delete" in bicep for azure service bus Subscription? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: did you try to just not set `autoDeleteOnIdle` (or set it to null)?

Answer (score 3):

From Azure portal, if you check `Never auto-delete` it will set the `autoDeleteOnIdle` like that:

```
autoDeleteOnIdle: 'P10675198DT2H48M5.477S'
```

Comment: The most magic number I've ever seen!

Comment: @Thomas Can you explain what this autoDeleteOnIdle means? Does it mean if autoDeleteOnIdle: '14D' is set, that the Azure Service Bus Subscription itself as a resource will be deleted completely in Azure Portal after 14 days if that subscription has not been received any messages for the last 14 days? Is this understood correctly?

Comment: @OliverNilsen Correct. The autoDeleteOnIdle is an ISO 8601 timespan idle interval after which the topic is automatically deleted. The minimum duration is 5 minutes.